# persistent cart login step

Tags: checkout, magento-1, session, persistent

In the persistent cart steps, customer is sent to the login page to re-enter the login information. What I want to do is if the customer is logged in (step also adds "Not" in welcome msg header), I want to auto populate email address in the login form. But since no sessions(customer and checkout) are available at this point I cant do it. What would be the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

You can get the customer id like this:

```
$sessionModel = Mage::helper('persistent/session');
$customerId = $sessionModel->getCustomerId();
```

then you can easily get the e-mail address.

```
$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($customerId);
$email = $customer->getEmail();
```